# What are the medical masks Japanese people wear called?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

What are the medical masks Japanese people wear called? The ones you see people just casually wearing; what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are simply referred to as マスク. This term refers exactly to the kind of mask you are asking about, as well as "more professional" masks such as the ones doctors/surgeons might use and so on.

There is also a [wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF) page about this.

Well to be more precise (since now I actually spent some time reading that wikipedia page), as you can see there there are technically several different types of masks (face mask, surgical mask, dust-protection mask) but after all all of them are mostly always simply called マスク. For your specific case (the ones people are often seen casually wearing), it's most likely the simple type use to reduce the spreading of viruses (cold/influenza) or to protect from the pollen allregy very common among Japanese people (花粉症{かふんしょう}).. and you can see in the following sentence they are just referred to as "mask" as I said above.

> 呼吸の際に外部からの埃や塵、花粉などを防ぐ用途に用いたり、また、風邪やインフルエンザの感染者のクシャミや咳などでウイルスを含んだ分泌物を外部に広く撒き散らしにくくする効果があり、風邪・インフルエンザに感染している患者は他人に伝染させない為、感染拡大を防ぐ為に**マスク**を着用する事が求められる。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！:D